# Can a build be marked as failed from an Xcode bot trigger script?

Tags: xcode6, appium, xcode-bots

I'm using a post-build trigger script in an Xcode bot to run some tests through Appium. I've gotten it to run, but I can't find any way to mark the build as failed if the tests fail.

Is this possible, or should I just email the results for now and wait to move to a different CI system? Documentation for these bot trigger scripts is sketchy at best.

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to do this? I agree the documentation is pretty sparse.

Comment: See https://github.com/czechboy0/Buildasaur which uses Xcode Server as the CI and GitHub as the reportee.